# PyQt5, prevent hide event when [start + D] pressed

Tags: python-3.x, event-handling, pyqt5

When the Start+D button is pressed, all window windows are hidden.

I'm looking for a way to not hide the window even when Start+D is pressed.

```py
def WindowStateChange(self, event):
    if self.isMinimized(): self.showNormal()

def hideEvent(self, event):
    if self.isMinimized(): self.activateWindow()
```

it deosn't work.

In fact, it works, but it is not in the state of entering start+D, but it is triggered late when an event occurs by operating another app on the taskbar.

Comment: If you're on Windows and the window is a "normal" window, it seems that it's impossible to do so with normal Qt, because since at least Windows 7 the event hiding the window is not propagated as it should. It might be possible to circumvent this by setting the `Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint` flag, but I'm not sure about this, and I'm afraid that the only solution is to use the win32 api as a workaround. See [this](https://forum.qt.io/topic/64896/disable-minimizing-of-application/4) and [this](https://forum.qt.io/topic/28711/prevent-minimize-window-when-click-show-desktop/3).

Comment: Also, look at the win32 related answer in this post (in this case the flag is `Qt.WindowStaysOnBottomHint`): [How to make pyqt app stay on bottom of all windows like Rainmeter?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64776014)